# php curl cookie_session and relocation

Tags: php, curl

**Situation:**

When entering site, it sets session cookie and redirects to itself.

**Problem:**

When using curl with `FOLLOW_RELOCATION` and `COOKIE_SESSION`, it does not apply the cookie after redirect and ends up with maximum redirection limit reached error.

**Code:**

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INTERFACE, $ip);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
```

**Verbose output:**

```
* About to connect() to www.thesite.org port 80 (#0)
*   Trying x.x.x.254... * Name 'x.x.29.61' family 2 resolved to 'x.x.29.61' family 2
* Local port: 0
* connected
* Connected to www.thesite.org (x.x.x.254) port 80 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: www.thesite.org
Accept: */*

< HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily
< Date: Wed, 31 Jul 2013 15:14:05 GMT
< Server: Apache
< cache-control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
< pragma: no-cache
< expires: Mon, 17 Jul 1978 05:00:00 GMT
< Last-Modified: Wed, 31 Jul 2013 15:14:05 GMT
< Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=0A2488FF811CCDAB6A6C95C12AA3F4F8.DB4B9335DF549E1FCF56CF5BD8; Path=/
< Location: http://www.thesite.org/
< Content-Length: 0
< Vary: Accept-Encoding
< Content-Type: text/html
< 
* Connection #0 to host www.thesite.org left intact
* Issue another request to this URL: 'http://www.thesite.org/'
* Re-using existing connection! (#0) with host www.thesite.org
* Connected to www.thesite.org (x.x.x.254) port 80 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: www.thesite.org
Accept: */*

< HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily
< Date: Wed, 31 Jul 2013 15:14:06 GMT
< Server: Apache
< cache-control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
< pragma: no-cache
< expires: Mon, 17 Jul 1978 05:00:00 GMT
< Last-Modified: Wed, 31 Jul 2013 15:14:06 GMT
< Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=5A80785B002D8C37F73F798B75A090B4.47EF37A843F03A8253F26BC644; Path=/
< Location: http://www.thesite.org/
< Content-Length: 0
< Vary: Accept-Encoding
< Content-Type: text/html
< 
* Connection #0 to host www.thesite.org left intact
* Issue another request to this URL: 'http://www.thesite.org/'
* Re-using existing connection! (#0) with host www.thesite.org
* Connected to www.thesite.org (x.x.x.254) port 80 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: www.thesite.org
Accept: */*

etc...
```

**The question is:**

What am I doing wrong? How to make it work? Of course I could connect two times and set it manually, but it's not what I would like to do, that's why I am using `CURL` and not `file_get_contents()`.

Comment: What code are you using to set up the curl handler?

Comment: Question edited, code above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code doesn't show that you're using a cookiefile to store information between page loads.

Add the following lines and it should work better.

```
$cookie_file='cookies.txt'; //Change this to wherever you want.
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie_file);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie_file);
```

Comment: Yes, and I don't want to use files to store cookies. No way to do a single request without storing anything? `curl_setopt($ch, CURL_COOKIEJAR, '/dev/null');` does not help.